# MySQL: combining multiple values after a join into one result column

Tags: mysql, sql, left-join, group-concat

I have a database with a table for publications, each of which can have multiple authors that are stored in a different table. I'd like to query the database into giving me a list of publication titles in one column, and the combined authors for that publication in the second.

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, a.`fullname` 
from `publications` p 
LEFT JOIN `authors` a on a.`publication_id` = p.`id`;
```

This of course gives me multiple times the publication title for as many authors.

```
id   title              fullname
--   -----              --------
1    Beneath the Skin   Sean French
1    Beneath the Skin   Nicci Gerrard
2    The Talisman       Stephen King
2    The Talisman       Peter Straub
```

Grouping on id gives me one author per title:

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, a.`fullname` 
from `publications` p 
LEFT JOIN `authors` a on a.`publication_id` = p.`id` 
GROUP BY a.`id`;

id   title              fullname
--   -----              --------
1    Beneath the Skin   Sean French
2    The Talisman       Stephen King
```

The result I'm looking for is this:

```
id   title              fullname
--   -----              --------
1    Beneath the Skin   Sean French, Nicci Gerrard
2    The Talisman       Stephen King, Peter Straub
```

I think the answer should be found in using GROUP_CONCAT, but the only result I'm able to get is one result row with all authors:

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, GROUP_CONCAT(a.`fullname`) from `publications` p 
LEFT JOIN `authors` a on a.`publication_id` = p.`id` 
GROUP BY a.`id`;

id   title              fullname
--   -----              --------
1    Beneath the Skin   Sean French, Nicci Gerrard, Stephen King, Peter Straub
```

And using GROUP_CONCAT after the join gives me an "Every derived table must have its own alias" error.

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, a.`fullname` 
FROM `publications` p 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(a.`fullname`) FROM `authors` a) ON a.`publication_id` = p.`id`;
```

Any clues?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You need to group by all of the non-aggregated columns in the SELECT  (and explicitly, not group by the author id, because author is part of the GROUP_CONCAT):

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, GROUP_CONCAT(a.`fullname` separator ', ')
from `publications` p 
LEFT JOIN `authors` a on a.`publication_id` = p.`id` 
GROUP BY p.`id`, p.`title`;
```

Answer (score 3):

Stuart's answer is fine.  This is just to show the working version of your approach:

```
SELECT p.`id`, p.`title`, a.`fullname`
FROM `publications` p LEFT JOIN
      (SELECT publication_id, GROUP_CONCAT(a.`fullname` separator ', ')
       FROM `authors` a
       GROUP BY publication_id
      ) a
--------^
      ON a.`publication_id` = p.`id`;
```

The error you got was because the `a` was missing after the subquery.  The subquery also needed to be fixed, to include `publication_id` in the `select` and a `group by` clause.