# Improving concatenated Left join queries in a single result row

Tags: mysql

I have two tables; `members` and `telephone`.

A member can have multiple telephone rows. Each telephone row can have flags set to indicate what type of phone number it is.

I need a result set that is a single row per member, containing all or some of the different telephone rows.

This is a concatenation of `LEFT JOINS` from different parts of the same table.

The database tables both have full indexes on all numeric columns.

## Table structures

*(probably not that important but here for completeness sake)*

**members:**

```
CREATE TABLE `members` (
 `mem_id` smallint(6) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 ...
 `reg` varchar(10) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT 'No Reg',
 PRIMARY KEY (`mem_id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=968 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

**Telephone:**

```
CREATE TABLE `telephone` (
 `tel_id` int(8) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
 `mem_id` int(8) NOT NULL,
 `tel_name` varchar(64) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
 `tel_num` varchar(24) COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci NOT NULL,
 `main` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `player` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N',
 `home` char(1) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'N' COMMENT 'Y= Home Phone',
 PRIMARY KEY (`tel_id`),
 KEY `memid` (`mem_id`),
 KEY `main` (`main`),
 KEY `player` (`player`),
 KEY `home` (`home`),
 KEY `telnum` (`tel_num`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=2237 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci
```

---

## My Query so far:

Aim of the query is to return a single row for each member detailing (amongst other data unshown) all their associated telephone numbers and being able to differenciate between each number:

The `WHERE`conditionals are only applied to the `members` table only.

```
SELECT members.mem_id, ... ,
       thome.tel_num as thome, tmob.tel_num as tmob, 
       twork.tel_num as twork
FROM members
LEFT JOIN telephone thome FROM telephone ON thome.mem_id = members.mem_id AND thome.home = 'Y'
LEFT JOIN telephone tmob FROM telephone ON tmob.mem_id = members.mem_id AND tmob.main = 'Y' AND tmob.tel_num LIKE '07%'
LEFT JOIN telephone twork FROM telephone ON twork.mem_id = members.mem_id AND twork.player = 'Y'
WHERE ...
```

---

## Example data:

**Members table:**

```
 memid | mname   |  reg 
---------------------------------
  22   | george  | 1456436456
```

**Telephone table:**

```
  tel_id | mem_id |   tel_name  |   tel_num    | main | player | home
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     1   |   22   |  Home phone | 01234 456463 |  N   |   N    |  Y
     12  |   22   |  Work phone | 01334 457893 |  Y   |   N    |  N
     19  |   22   |  Mobile num | 07564 456333 |  N   |   Y    |  N
     23  |   22   |  Home phone | 01987 657353 |  N   |   N    |  N
```

**Desired Result:**

```
 memid | mname  |     reg    |  twork  |  tmob   |  thome  | etc...   
-------------------------------------------------------------------
  22   | george | 1456436456 | 01334...| 07564...| 01234...| ...
```

---

## Notes:

- I'm aware that the flag columns (`main`, `player`, etc.) could be ENUMs
- I'm also aware the tables could be InnoDB and have foreign keys setup.

*(I'm not at all against either of these things it's just a case of getting round to them)*

- None of the telephone numbers are required so while I am aware `INNER JOIN` is more efficient; it can't be used in this case.
- `GROUP_CONCAT` doesn't work on a per-column basis as each column is selected by differet criteria (flags). Maybe it can work on a broader setting but each `tel_num` value would need to be renamed (*I think I could use some guidance on using `GROUP_CONCAT` in this situation*).
- Flags are **not** mutually exclusive: a telephone row could be  `|  Y  |   Y   |  Y` . But each member only has *one* of each flag.
- All the phone numbers are active, some will have no flags and so not need to be returned.

---

Question:

## Can I improve my SQL query to not need three seperate `LEFT JOIN`s?

---

**Other questions I've looked at with similar issues:**

- [Mysql - optimisation - multiple group_concat & joins using having](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37413701/mysql-optimisation-multiple-group-concat-joins-using-having)
- [INNER or LEFT Joining Multiple Table Records Into A Single Row](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2567460/inner-or-left-joining-multiple-table-records-into-a-single-row)
- [MySQL: combining multiple values after a join into one result column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21553721/mysql-combining-multiple-values-after-a-join-into-one-result-column)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without changing your current schema, I don't see a way to improve your current query, other than perhaps trying to tune it with indices etc.  However, I can make a suggested change in your table design which can lend itself to a much simpler query for the output you want.  Consider refactoring the `telephone` table to the following:

```
  tel_id | mem_id |   tel_name  |   tel_num    | type | active
-----------------------------------------------------------------------
     1   |   22   |  Home phone | 01234 456463 |  1   | 1
     12  |   22   |  Work phone | 01334 457893 |  2   | 1
     19  |   22   |  Mobile num | 07564 456333 |  3   | 1
     23  |   22   |  Home phone | 01987 657353 |  1   | 0
```

Now if you want a query which will retrieve the active home, work, and mobile numbers for each member, the following should suffice:

```
SELECT
    m.memid,
    m.mname,
    m.reg,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tel_name ORDER BY t.type) names,
    GROUP_CONCAT(t.tel_num ORDER BY t.type) numbers
FROM members m
LEFT JOIN telephone t
    ON m.mem_id = t.mem_id AND
       t.active = 1
GROUP BY
    m.memid;
```

I have assumed here that each member will always have some entry for the home, work, and mobile numbers, even if that entry should be null or empty string.  I also assume that you only want to report the active numbers.  If you need to report all numbers, then a group concat solution becomes less attractive, because you might get back a long CSV string and it might not be intuitive how to read it.

**Edit:**

We can also `GROUP_CONCAT` the telephone name labels.  This means that each record in the result set will have, in addition to a CSV list of numbers, the corresponding phone number types.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion -- I hadn't considered changing the flagging schema (at least, beyond `ENUM`ing it).

Comment: If a member does not have a `type` (certainly will be an issue for some members) then will that confuse the results of the `GROUP_CONCAT` such as if a member had no `type=2` number the type 1 and 3 are returned but show as if type 1 and 2 ?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I will build in a `type` column and test out the query and see how the results look. Cheers.

Comment: Ah ok another snag -- what if rows have multiple flags (some do) ; I would need to generate a type for each combination, so for 3 flags thats 9 types (8 + 1 for none), and this makes the ordering of types a mess `:-/`

Comment: What you are suggesting/worrying about is not normalized data.  In my suggested table, if a single number were simultaneously the home, work, and cell number, then there would be three separate records to record this.  Yes, it is wasteful, but if you expect this happening a lot we could normalize this away so that we store the actual numbers in a separate table.

Comment: @Martin Read my above comment, this is not a problem.

Comment: Ah ok now I comprehend. `:-)`